# stackoverflow error recursion square root

Tags: java, recursion

I am getting a stackoverflow error when I run my program. I am quite knew to java and I could use a bit of advice.

Any help is appreciated!

```
public class ApproxSquareRoot {

public static float sqrRootRec(float number, float approx, float tol) {
    if((Math.abs((Math.pow(approx,2) - number))<= tol*number)) {
       return approx;
    } else
       return sqrRootRec(number, (approx*approx + number/(2*approx)),tol);


}

public static float sqrRoot(float number, float approx, float tol) {

     while (Math.abs((Math.pow(approx,2) - number))<= tol*number)
     approx = (approx*approx + number)/(approx + approx);
     return approx;
}

}
```

.

```
Input number: 43
Input approx: 2.5
Input tol: .1
Output with number = 43.0 approx = 2.5 tolerance = 0.1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Comment: Have you researched what a `StackOverflowError` is?

Comment: You are probably getting an infinite recursion.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how do I fix that.. can you help?

Comment: Check the answer below as it seems to be on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, please research what a [`StackOverflowError`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror) is, but regardless of that, I shall point out where you are getting a problem. For your recursive calculation, the next estimate is calculated as follows:

```
return sqrRootRec(number, (approx*approx + number/(2*approx)),tol);
```

However, for the iterative case, there is:

```
approx = (approx*approx + number)/(approx + approx);
```

Note that these two approximations are not equal, so although I haven't checked the maths, if you make your `sqrRootRec` function use the second form, it should solve the `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 0):

In your iterative function, the next iteration becomes:

```
(approx*approx + number)/(approx + approx)
```

In your recursive function, it becomes:

```
(approx*approx + number/(2*approx))
```

As you see, the parentheses are different. Your recursive function can be written as:

```
(approx*approx + (number/(2*approx)))
```

For the iterative function, after one iteration the value becomes:

```
(2.5 * 2.5 + 43) / (2.5 + 2.5) = 9.85
```

But for your recursive function it is:

```
(2.5 * 2.5 + (43 / (2 * 2.5))) = 14.85
```

That's quite different. Fix the location of the parentheses [the `(` and `)`] and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it!